# Play/Pause music when clicking on image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to this. I created my first html site this week.
One thing that I included on my page was an image that starts dancing (gif) when you click it. When I click it again, it goes back to normal (png). This worked. I also used the following javascript to trigger audio when I click  the image. So the image starts dancing and music plays.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function playSound(soundfile) {
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
    "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" 
    loop=\"false\" />"; 

    }
```

When I click the image and it stops dancing though, the music starts again. I want it to pause and when I click it again, continue playing. 
I hope this makes sense and I hope someone could help me out. Sorry if I'm being
vague or if it doesn't make sense, as I said I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Have you considered using the `<audio>` tag instead?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code snippet - it uses an `<audio>` tag to achieve what you want:

```html
<img src="http://www.bioprocessintl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/audio.jpg" data-state="play"/>
<audio src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg" preload>
    Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> tag
</audio>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var state = e.currentTarget.dataset.state;
    if (state == "play") {
        //play the gif aswell
     document.querySelector("audio").play();
        e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "pause";
    }
    else {
        //pause the gif aswell
     document.querySelector("audio").pause();
        e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "play";
    } 
});
</script>
```

Click the image anywhere to trigger it!

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for you help. I tried but as I said I'm not sure if I did it right because I'm innexperienced. Adding a button which triggers the audio works, but I can't seem to replace it with an image. Could you maybe give me an example? And how do I trigger the audio when I click the image, but change it aswell (it changes into a gif so it starts moving.)?

Comment: @Elle I updated my example to use an img instead. You already have the code that plays/pauses the gif, right? just put that code in the `if - else` block where applicable