# Making an image plays a sound on-click -- but doesn't always work after?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to create an HTML page that includes images that play sounds on-click. The first click for every image works great, but subsequent clicks don't always work; they seem to require some refractory load time again?

I have three audio files: "two.mp3" "five.mp3" and "one.mp3". I also have three different colored circle images that the audio files are assigned to. My code is based on the Stack Overflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549356/play-pause-music-when-clicking-on-image).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <script src= "drag.js"></script>
  </head>

    <img id="a" src="jspsych/img/blue.png" class="dragme" data-state="play"/>
    <audio id = "two" src="jspsych/audio/five.mp3" preload>
        Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> tag
    </audio>

    <img id="b" src="jspsych/img/orange.png" class="dragme" data-state="play"/>
    <audio id = "five" src="jspsych/audio/two.mp3" preload>
        Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> tag
    </audio>

    <img id="c" src="jspsych/img/black.png" class="dragme" data-state="play"/>
    <audio id = "one" src="jspsych/audio/one.mp3" preload>
        Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> tag
    </audio>


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


        document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click", function(e){
            var state = e.currentTarget.dataset.state;
            if (state == "play") {
                document.querySelector("audio").play();
                e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "pause";
            }
            else {
                document.querySelector("audio").pause();
                e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "play";
            }   
        });

        document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(e){
            var state = e.currentTarget.dataset.state;
            if (state == "play") {
                document.getElementById("five").play();
                e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "pause";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("five").pause();
                e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "play";
            }   
        });

        document.getElementById("c").addEventListener("click", function(e){
            var state = e.currentTarget.dataset.state;
            if (state == "play") {
                document.getElementById("one").play();
                e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "pause";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("one").pause();
                e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "play";
            }   
        });


    </script>

</html>
```

Might anyone have some idea for improvement?

Comment: Does it take time to load??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to play it again after you set the state to "play":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <script src="drag.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img id="a" src="jspsych/img/blue.png" class="dragme" data-state="play" />
  <audio id="two" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" preload>
        Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> tag
    </audio>

  <img id="b" src="jspsych/img/orange.png" class="dragme" data-state="play" />
  <audio id="five" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" preload>
        Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> tag
    </audio>

  <img id="c" src="jspsych/img/black.png" class="dragme" data-state="play" />
  <audio id="one" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/horse.mp3" preload>
        Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> tag
    </audio>


  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var state = e.currentTarget.dataset.state;
      if (state == "play") {
        document.querySelector("audio").play();
        e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "pause";
      } else {
        document.querySelector("audio").pause();
        e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "play";
        document.querySelector("audio").play();
      }
    });

    document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var state = e.currentTarget.dataset.state;
      if (state == "play") {
        document.getElementById("five").play();
        e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "pause";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("five").pause();
        e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "play";
        document.getElementById("five").play();
      }
    });

    document.getElementById("c").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      var state = e.currentTarget.dataset.state;
      if (state == "play") {
        document.getElementById("one").play();
        e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "pause";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("one").pause();
        e.currentTarget.dataset.state = "play";
        document.getElementById("one").play();
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that the audio file is loaded while the page is loaded so for the first time it plays correctly without any delay, now since the file is coming from the internet it takes some loading time also not to forget that you mentioned `preload` attribute in audio tag, this means audio has to be loaded entirely prior to playing, so in your case you can add the line below wherever you are playing the audio

```
//Replace this
document.getElementById("one").play()
```

```
//With this
document.getElementById("one").oncanplaythrough=function(){
this.play()
}
```

The above line loads chunks of file enough in the buffer so that it can be played and so it would reduce delay to much extent and I think it might help you, also you need to remove `preload` from audio tag